# Doze whitelist and deviceidle.xml

Tags: android, whitelist, doze

I'm trying to add my package in doze whitelist.

With `($ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +PACKAGE)`, I can add my package in whitelist,

and this command makes change in the **`file /data/system/deviceidle.xml.`**

Now, I'm curious about who generate `deviceidle.xml.`

Is there anyone who knows about `deviceidle.xml`?

Answer (score 2):

I found a clue in framework module,

**`IDeviceController.addPowerSaveWhitelistApp(String name)`** helps to add my package into ;

also, /data/system/deviceidle.xml is updated.

You can check with adb dumpsys

`$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle`

`$ adb shell cat /data/system/deviceidle.xml`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, doze whitelisting is done by system creators. 
You can ask user for whitelisting via intent action: Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS.

In the [DeviceIdleController soruce code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/DeviceIdleController.java) you can see that it reads deviceidle.xml
in constructor. It might be that, if you know the file structure and have rooted device you can manually create and edit this file.

```
  @VisibleForTesting DeviceIdleController(Context context, Injector injector) {
    super(context);
    mInjector = injector;
    mConfigFile = new AtomicFile(new File(getSystemDir(), "deviceidle.xml"));
    [...]
}
```